# CakePHP - Where is the best place to put custom utility classes in my app structure?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am making utility classes that will provide general methods for helping manipulate strings.  I may also want one for arrays, math functions, etc.  Should these be components?  Vendors?  Could I maybe make these into some sort of vendor package?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261432/how-to-use-common-function-in-helper-and-component-in-cakephp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768816/where-to-save-a-custom-class-and-how-to-load-it-in-a-cakephp-component

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If they're general standalone libraries not tied to any particular step of the request cycle (controller, model, view), put them in `app/libs/`. You can import them using `App::import('Lib', 'Foo')`.

Personally I have two or three handy array functions I always use defined in `bootstrap.php`, which is another place to put *a small amount* of global stuff.

Comment: How would you do this in cakephp3? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955881/include-utility-class-all-over-the-application-cakephp-3