# WHere to save a custom class and how to load it in a CakePHP Component?

Tags: php, cakephp, components

I have a custom class named MathLib.php and I need to use some login inside this class in all the controllers. Reading CakePHP documentations I found that components are the best way to do this. But Now, I have a problem, I would like to know **where** do I have to save the MathLib.php class (in what Folder do i have to put custom class), and How can I load it in a component.

Thank you!

Comment: Surely not version 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you wrote the custom class, you put it in `app\libs` for cake 1.x and in `app\Lib` for cake 2.x, if not it goes inside the app\vendors or app\Vendor.

To load it in a component for cake 2.x you would add before your component class declaration:

```
App::uses('MathLib', 'Lib');
```

The class name and file name should be the same.

For 1.x you would load it by:

```
App::import('Lib', 'MathLib');
```

More info for 1.x here http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1579/Library-classes

If it's a vendor, same idea, but read these docs: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/944/Vendor-examples.

It's the file naming that's important.

Comment: @tjgrang perfect! thank you...but inside the component how to create the object? normal way? $obj = new MathLib() ?

Comment: Yea. The component is essentially being a wrapper for your custom class if I understand correctly. But  I don't know if its worth it. Can't you import it in AppController and  and instantiate it there to then use in all your controllers. That seems easier.

Comment: @tjgrang, uh right! I can import it in the main AppController so it will be used but in the AppCOntroller do i only have to use: App::uses('MathLib', 'Lib') without do nothing inside the AppController class ?

Comment: You would still have to instantiate it. Add `public $MathLib;` as an class instance var, then in beforeFilter or __construct instantiate it.

Comment: +1 short and concise, to bad the links to the docs are dead and the searching revels nothing about Library-classes in cake 1.3 docs. (It's not the first time this happens, I think Cake devs have a bad habit to reorganize the docs by changing links or completely erasing parts).