# cakephp components and helpers breaks oop logic! How should I proceed?

Tags: php, class, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a string manipulation class that I need in views and in controllers also!
I saw that cake reuses code in Components and in Helpers for this type of situations which on my opinion breaks the OOP logic (eg. Session->read)!

Instead of doing this I created a vendor class which I imported in a StringsHelper and in a StringsComponent. I then created an identical function which instanciates the Vendor/String class and returns the results from the corresponding function. This is not quite inheritance and still redundant, but if I change code in my class it changes everywhere.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: dont use vendor clases here (since it is not a third party product), use Libs (APP/Lib)

Comment: why would you care about OOP principles and concepts when you are already using CakePHP ?

Comment: I am supposed to port an entire app, developed by OOP principles! Which is now supposed to be part of a bigger app developed with cake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to wrap this kind of class in a Helper or a Component.

You could simply create a class with static methods and put it in `APP/Lib` like mentioned by Mark.

```
<?php
class StringTool{

  public static function manipulate($string){
   ...
  }

}
```

and then use it in whatever class you need, wether in a Component, a Helper, a Model, etc.

```
<?php
$s2 = StringTool::manipulate($s1);
```

Comment: I want to use it in a controller and in views, thus I have a Component and a **Helper**. If I still have to pass through them and call functions from my class the situation is the same. My main problem is with the view, otherwise I would've put the code in a Component and that was it, but I need a helper too. I understood why should I move in Lib, it is correct, but it still doesn't help me! Is there a way to call it directly in view?

Comment: same answer: you could use `StringTool::manipulate($s1)` directly in your views or controllers as well, without creating any component or helper. Controllers and views are just PHP, so you can call any lib you want in them.

Comment: static methods have nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: I understand now! I thought you where saying something like create a Helper and call it there, which was basically the same thing I was already doing, but from another place. Now I saw that I can import it in my Controller and it is available for the view also. No OOP here, but I got the needed result and that is keeping my classes clean!

Answer (score 0):

I asked this same question before.  Best place is in app/Libs, where you can put a class with static helper functions that can be used anywhere in your application, including controllers and views.

Import the class using `App::import('Lib', 'YourClass')`

[CakePHP - Where is the best place to put custom utility classes in my app structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307083/cakephp-where-is-the-best-place-to-put-custom-utility-classes-in-my-app-struct)