# Include utility class all over the application cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have custom utility class that contains some methods for general use and it is located in src/Utility/UtilityClass.

I can include the Utility class in controller .e.g.

```
use App\Utility\ArrayUtil;
```

and then call the class in my controllers e.g.

```
ArrayUtil::myMethod();
```

And it works. I need to include the UtilityClass in bootstrap so it applies all over the application so I can reuse it in models, templates and other controllers as well.

I tried to load it in config/bootstrap.php but I get this error:

> Error: Class 'ArrayUtil' not found

Any idea

Comment: I did explain to you that PHP imports work on a per-file basis. Was there really a need to delete your question and repost this?

Comment: @ndm Please try it your self then you understand what I mean. You are giving me an other approach (creating a view helper) or answers like Object Manipulator. That doesn't work for me. It has to be proper way not any thing comes first in mind.

Comment: I never mentioned helpers, all I'm saying is that this simply is how PHP namespaces work, and you should learn to deal with it, as this is how things are working in nearly any modern PHP library. Trying to reintroduce these CakePHP 1/2.x autoloading concepts is anything but a good idea.

Comment: @ndm Thank you. I have already started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this line at the top of the page, be it Model, view or controller.

```
 use App\Utility\ArrayUtil;
```

If you're using this utility in multiple views, then I'd suggest you to write this line in Template/Layout/default.ctp, since all templates would be a part of this.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: PHP imports have a per-file scope, adding them in a layout file will not affect other view templates.

Comment: Thank you but that's not how I do it. Normally in cake 2 I use to load the utility in bootstrap.php  but in cake3 doesn't work. I believe in bootstrap not only my custom but some of the other classes are not loading e.g.

Comment: Cake 2 doesn't use namepsaces, Cake 3 does, that's the big difference which won't allow you to achieve what you did in Cake 2. In Cake 3 you will need the ` use App\Utility\ArrayUtil;` in every file you want to use your class.